# Why does `ave` with `table` return character when first argument is character?

Tags: r, grouping

Consider two vectors `v1`and `v2`,

```
v1 <- c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
v2 <- as.character(v1)
```

where their `table`s give identical numerical output.

```
table(v1)
# v1
# 1 2 3 
# 2 3 4 
table(v2)
# v1
# 1 2 3 
# 2 3 4
```

Now, `ave`ing with numerics as first argument gives `"numeric"`:

```
ave(v1, v1, FUN=table)
# [1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2
ave(v1, v2, FUN=table)
# [1] 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2
```

Whereas character as first argument gives `"character"`:

```
ave(v2, v1, FUN=table)
# [1] "4" "4" "4" "4" "3" "3" "3" "2" "2"
ave(v2, v2, FUN=table)
# [1] "4" "4" "4" "4" "3" "3" "3" "2" "2"
```

Documentation of `ave` says:

> **Value** 
> A numeric vector, say `y` of length `length(x)`. [...]

For me that means it should always return `"numeric"`.

**Is this a bug or a feature?**

Comment: ... but the documentation of `ave` also says that the first argument `x` should or is expected to be a `numeric`.

Comment: @stefan Yeah I've noticed that. Since `table` always yields numeric, I still find it contradictory. Why should the result coerced into character. `?ave` doesn't say that the result is coerced in to the original class of first argument.

Comment: I see your point. Probably the docs should be more clearer on this or at least mention how the return value is determined.

Comment: ... one more example: `ave(v1, v2, FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))` gives a character as one would expect but definitly no numeric. (;

Comment: @stefan I don't understand your example, `paste()`  and `ave(., paste)` yield identical class, whereas `table()` and `ave(., table)` yield different.

Comment: Sorry. Just wanted to show that the return value is not solely determined by the type of `x` (as in your example with table) but depends also on the return value of the function. In this sense just an example that the docs could be improved.

Comment: @stefan Ah sure ok! In your example, numeric input gives character output, sorry!

Comment: Related threads on R-help where you get the developers view of the topic: [ave(x, y, FUN=length) produces character output when x is character](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-December/thread.html#424391); [function ave() with seq_along returning char sequence instead of numeric](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-November/thread.html#442844). `ave` a nice day!

Comment: @Henrik Well, they seem to have shared a rather passionate commitment to each other in 2014, didn't they? Finally I feel [William](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-December/424397.html) came to the point, and of course your [2016 link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-November/thread.html#442844). Thanks for sharing!

Comment: _Passionate commitment_ is indeed an euphemism. So many incredibly smart and helpful people on that list, but you can for sure get flamed. Most often deservedly. No waving emojis...